# SQL Server: Why SELECT * INTO is faster than SELECT * (network excluded)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

Why would Query2 dramatically outperform Query1?

**Query1:**

```
SELECT * FROM [SomeComplexView];
```

Takes 4 minutes, does not use parallelism in query plan

**Query2:**

```
SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM [SomeComplexView];
SELECT * FROM #t1;
```

Takes 15 seconds, uses parallelism. I guess the answer should be quite simple and generic, so I omit the complexities of the view.

Comment: Perhaps the storage for temporary tables is much, much faster than the storage used for returning result sets.  You can also check the execution plans.

Comment: The first likely leads to a trivial plan that streams the rows sequentially and has no additional storage use. The second one can make use of parallelism in the `SELECT .. INTO` -- and then you still get a trivial plan that streams the rows sequentially, but straight from an already written table. The answer is almost certainly dependent on "the complexities of the view" as well, however, since the optimizer effectively treats the view as a subquery. There are various reasons why the optimizer might not get parallel; the query plan (in XML form) often explains why.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any common reason why an optimizer might choose a parallel plan for 'SELECT * INTO' #temptable, but choose a sequential plan for the same query without an 'INTO' clause?

Comment: An `INSERT` will already consume disk space by the very nature of the operation; a `SELECT` normally does not. It wouldn't be surprising for the optimizer to be more conservative if (say) a sort step required storage. This isn't necessarily always the case, though, sometimes the optimizer just bails out early and fails to consider the proper benefits of parallelism. You can experiment with `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649)`, which forces the use of parallelism if possible. This should not be a first resort; things like wrong row counts from outdated statistics should be fixed first, if necessary.

Comment: Check **cost threshold for parallelism** parameter on your server. The threshold seems to be exceeded by the second query.

Answer (score 0):

http://dataeducation.com/next-level-parallel-plan-forcing-an-alternative-to-8649/

> When the query optimizer decides whether or not to select a parallel
>   plan, it first comes up with a serial plan cost, then compares it to
>   the parallel plan cost. If the parallel plan cost is lower, that’s the
>   one that gets used. This parallel plan cost is based on the serial
>   cost, but with a few key modifications:...

```
--estimated plans
--serial cost:399
--parallel cost:204 <---!
select a.*
into #abc
from master.dbo.spt_values as a
cross join master.dbo.spt_values as b
--option(maxdop 1) 
--option (maxdop 2)


--serial cost: 28 <---!
--parallelx2 cost:41
--parallelx4 cost:20 
--parallelx8 cost:10
select a.*
from master.dbo.spt_values as a
cross join master.dbo.spt_values as b
--option (maxdop 1)
--option (querytraceon 8649, maxdop 2)
```